# How to centralize table elements using the tabular environment?

Tags: tables

Please, how do I centralize a table and its elements using the tabular environment. I entered the following code, which centralized the table quite alright but the elements of the table are still flushed left. Thank you in advance. See code below:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.2in}|p{1.0in}|p{1.3in}|} \hline 
 & $M$ & $N$ \\ \hline 
1 & $a_1,a_1,b_1,c_1,d_2$ & $a_1,a_1,b_1,b_1,c_1,d_2$ \\ \hline 
2 & $c_2,c_2,d_3,d_3,d_3$ & $c_2,c_2,d_3,$ \\ \hline 
3 & $d_4$ & $d_4$ \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}` although i would leave out the vertical rules and most of the others.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in multiple ways, as defining a new column type(provided by `Johannes_B`, which is great when you are reusing the new column a lot.

Setting the width manually is not always necessary, as LaTeX does this by itself, but of course there might be situations where it will not. You could do this for center columns like this: `>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}`, which we put into your code like this along with the defined column type`\begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.2in}MM}`. This should probably be improved.

Also, the `center`environment does add some vertical space. You should probably use `\centering`instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{$}c<{$}}% M as in math
\begin{document}
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{cMM}
        \toprule
                 & M                   & N                       \\
         \midrule
         1       & a_1,a_1,b_1,c_1,d_2 & a_1,a_1,b_1,b_1,c_1,d_2 \\
         2       & c_2,c_2,d_3,d_3,d_3 & c_2,c_2,d_3,            \\
         3       & d_4                 & d_4                     \\ 
         \bottomrule
     \end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

[image]